# C++ - How can I get the .exe path of a running process as an std::string?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a program that needs to place a file in the same directory as an already-running Windows process. How can I retrieve this directory as an std::string so that I can write in the correct place?

I know this isn't much of a question, but I did search with Google a lot, and I couldn't find anything even remotely similar to a solution.

EDIT: I'm using Code::Blocks, so a solution that isn't specific to the features of a single IDE would be best.

Comment: [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx) will proabbly come in handy for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get path name of current process, use `GetModuleFilename` as mentioned earlier.

To get path name of another process, use `GetModuleFileNameEx`. Unicode example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Psapi")

int main()
{
    wchar_t buf[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD pid = 123;
    std::cout << pid << std::endl;
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
    if (handle)
    {
        GetModuleFileNameExW(handle, 0, buf, MAX_PATH);
        CloseHandle(handle);
        std::wcout << buf << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code needs "Psapi.lib" library

Comment: ps, in Code::Blocks the Psapi library should be at `"%MinGW%\lib\libpsapi.a"`

Answer (score 2):

If you develop your program for Windows, you can use GetModuleFilename() API call and then remove filename part from whole path. Here is example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

bool MakeNearFilename(const wstring& strPreferredFilename, wstring& strOutputFilename)
{
    WCHAR strExePath[MAX_PATH];
    if (!::GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, strExePath, _countof(strExePath))) {
        return false;
    }

    match_results<const WCHAR*> results;
    if (regex_match(strExePath, results, wregex(L"^(.+\\\\)?(.+?)\\.exe$"))) {
        strOutputFilename = wstring(results[1]) + strPreferredFilename);
    }
    else {
        strOutputFilename = strPreferredFilename;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    wstring strFilename;
    MakeNearFilename(L"MyProgram.log", strFilename);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What is _countof? I'm getting a "not declared in this scope" error and Google isn't telling me what it's a part of.

Comment: Then you can just use or MAX_PATH or sizeof(strExePath) / sizeof(strExePath[0]) instead of _countof(strExePath).

Comment: I'm also getting "error: no matching function for call to 'regex_match(WCHAR [260], std::match_results<const char*>&, std::wregex)'|"

Comment: Problem in mixed WCHAR and const char*. What do you use? The code compiles ok, probably you have replaced unicode strings in my code with usual strings. Then you should also replace regex to regex("^(.+\\\\)?(.+?)\\.exe$")

Comment: It doesn't compile for me, and I didn't change anything. I'm also having a very hard time understanding these errors. I changed wregex to regex as you suggested, and got this error: "no matching function for call to 'std::basic_regex<char>::basic_regex(const wchar_t [20])'|"

Comment: By the way, I'm using Code::Blocks and not Visual Studio.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it by changing TCHAR to WCHAR. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, my fault ( WCHAR should be used if you had no unicode define in your project settings.

Comment: Oh... This is useful, but it turns out this actually gets the path of the _current_ process, not the path of another one. What I'm trying to do is get the path of another process that I have the PID for.